# RTTI Support for Clang with Microsoft CodeGen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, clang, rtti

I am trying to build a C++ project designed to be compiled using Clang on linux using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I am giving it a try since clang with microsoft codegen feature has been recently added to VS 2015) ( [article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351372/how-to-compile-c-for-windows-with-clang-in-visual-studio-2015) and [article2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/04/introducing-clang-with-microsoft-codegen-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx)) . However, I am getting the following compilation error while doing so - no matching function call for invoke. I get this error after I force enable rtti (run time type identification) feature in VS to fix other compilation errors. I am curious to know whether clang with codegen can support rtti to start with as it only changes C1 and not C2 of MS visual C++ compiler.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry that you're having trouble. RTTI affects both the front-end (c1) and the libraries and can have impact on the code generator (c2). We likely have some work to do here. 


Is it possible you can send a repro to us? You can send mail either to me--my StackOverflow name@microsoft.com--or to clangc2@microsoft.com.

Thank you!